# Conditional logic not working as expected

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a navigation that changes appearance (adds class 'color-swap' to header) past a given point (120px on the Y axis) on scroll.  This works just fine.  But before that given point, I want the links (on hover) to add that same class to the header, but only before the given point.  Sorry if this is confusing but I don't know how to better describe it.

I've added an event listener (scroll) that checks for the given point and changes my data attribute to false past the 120 point.  Within the scroll listener is a function that should quit if the data attribute is false.  When the page is scrolled past the 120 point, the data attribute changes to false as expected.  The problem is that the function doesn't quit, and goes on to execute the other condition that should only execute before the 120 point.  I want to add the class 'color-swap' if a header link is hovered over before the window scrolls to 120px, but I also want it added after the 120px point with normal link behavior (no class added to header).

If this doesn't make sense please feel free comment and I can try to elaborate further.

Also, there are different headers for 'News' and 'Contact' pages, so that's what that is all about.

Here is my php/WP markup:

```
<header data-is-top="true" id="header">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <nav id="site-navigation">

                         <?php wp_nav_menu(
                            array(
                                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                                'container'      => '',
                            )
                        );
                        ?>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And the JS:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        const header = document.getElementById('header');
        let prevSt = 0;
        let links = document.querySelectorAll("#primary-menu > .menu-item-has-children");

        function colorSwapScroll() {

            window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
                st = $(this).scrollTop();

                if (!window.location.pathname.startsWith('/about/contact') && !window.location.pathname.startsWith('/news')) {

                    if (st > 120) {
                        header.classList.add('color-swap');
                        header.setAttribute('data-is-top', 'false');
                    }
                    else {
                        header.classList.remove('color-swap');
                        header.setAttribute('data-is-top', 'true');
                    }
                    prevSt = st;
                }
            });

            function checkIsTop() {
                if (header.dataset.isTop === 'false') {
                    return;

                } else {

                    links.forEach((link, i) => {
                        link.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
                            header.classList.add('color-swap');
                        })
                        link.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
                            header.classList.remove('color-swap');
                        })
                    })


                }
            }
            checkIsTop();
        }

        colorSwapScroll();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is a link to a Codepen that recreates the problem https://codepen.io/jpaul1982/pen/GRGwxMq

Comment: @Yogi Thank you for the comment!  You're right, it does have problems - which is why I posted the question.  My css selector returns all the header links as expected, but that's not part of the issue.  The event handlers in checkIsTop() are indeed called, which I thought was implied by the fact that they are adding/removing the class.  The issue is that I expected checkIsTop to quit when my data attribute is set to false.  Does that help?

Comment: I've updated my posting with a codepen to help illustrate the problem.

Comment: In your mouse events you need to first test if data-is-top is true before you add or remove the color-swap class.  See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgkxdo7f/) example.